# Laravel 5.5 autodiscovery not registering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backup

I'm installing the `spatie\laravel-backup` package. According to the instructions, I just need to `composer require spatie\laravel-backup` and the package should be recognized and auto-installed. It looks like this is happening:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-backup
```

But looking in `/config/app.php` there's no mention of `backup` anywhere in the providers, and the expected `/config/backup.php` configuration file isn't found.

Are there any additional commands I need to issue to complete the auto-discovery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But looking in /config/app.php there's no mention of backup anywhere in the providers, and the expected /config/backup.php configuration file isn't found.

Laravel 5.5 does not modify your configuration files when it discovers packages. We only need to add service provider entries and facade aliases to *config/app.php* when *manually* registering a package's services.

Package discovery works by reading *vendor/composer/installed.json* to find autoloadable packages. It then saves a cached manifest file that the application reads when it boots to load the package providers and aliases (typically in *bootstrap/cache/packages.php*).

We can reload this cached package manifest file by running:

```
php artisan package:discover
```

Package discovery does *not* publish a package's assets, such as the configuration file you describe. The developer must explicitly run the `vendor:publish` command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Spatie\Backup\BackupServiceProvider'
```

This limitation is by design. Laravel has no way to know if the developer wants to publish a package's components, because, in many cases, packages provide optional components and the developer can choose which ones to publish.

Comment: This probably means you need to issue `php artisan vendor:publish` to copy the config files.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php artisan vendor:publish` to publish the config file.